# Odd sampling for symmetric functions?

Tags: sampling, symmetry

I have just started my first proper course in DSP, and am a little confused about a statement in my textbook.  The book states:

"Notice that when the Nyqust-frequency is **defined** as $\pi/\Delta t$, we will with $\omega_m = 2 \pi m/N \Delta t$ where $m = 0, \pm 1, \pm2, ...$ have $\omega_m \neq \pi/ \Delta t$, unless $N$ is even.  If we are working with symmetric functions, it can be wise to use an odd number of sampling points."

I see the logic in the first sentence here, but don't understand how it follows from this that it is wise to use an odd number of sampling points for a symmetric function. This statement is not elaborated upon further. Can anyone explain this logic to me?  Why it is wise to use an odd number of sampling points for a symmetric function?  If anyone could explain this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because it is symmetric about m = 0. So if you have an odd number of points then you can also sample at +/-1, +/-2, and so on. Thus each of the points has it's counterpart except for zero. This only works with an odd number of points.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  But why exactly doesn't it work with an even number of points?  Sorry for asking so much, but this is really new to me!

Comment: Never mind.  I got it now :).  Thanks a lot again!